# how to exclude listitem url from the search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We have several documents with 'SharePoint' in the title but our Online URL also has sharepoint (https://.sharepoint.com/).When users search for sharepoint in search results webpart, it returns all results because all results have that in their URL.

How can we exclude this portion of the URL from the search results?

Answer (score 0):

If this is only relevant for the keyword "Sharepoint" I would think that the best option is to add a Query rule. This could either promote those results where the title field contains the keyword or by changing the ranking to put those on top.

Answer (score 0):

To only return documents with 'SharePoint' in the title, you can search with managed property of the column, like the following:

Filename:SharePoint.

Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference